# ESC/POS Printing from iOS returns "Undefined symbol: _OBJC_$_regoPrinter"

Tags: ios, undefined-symbol, escpos

I've downloaded the official version of the SDK for the [Rego Printer](http://www.regotek.com/product/showproduct.php?lang=en&id=39).

This is the [original SDK Link](https://www.jianguoyun.com/p/DZYx_NcQgunxBhj-g2s).

I downloaded as it is, I tried running it on the Simulator and I get this error:

`Undefined symbol: _OBJC_$_regoPrinter`

[image]

While if I try running it directly on the iPhone I get this (which looks the same to me):

[image]

I've tried contacting the printer manufacturer but with no luck.

What does it mean and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: The message "ignoring...." is probably a clue; it seems to have a problem with the library. What does that message say in full?

Comment: @Paulw11 I updated the image to show the whole error, looks like an architecture error, which I don't know if it means iPhone architecture or my Mac arch (64bit)?

Comment: That error means that the library doesn't include a 64 bit x86 architecture, which is required to run on the simulator.  What error do you get if you run it on an iOS device?

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks, I've added the other screen

Comment: That second screen is also for a simulator build